# configure java daemon with systemd

Tags: systemd, java, daemon

I'm using this definition for a `systemd` job:

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Some job

 [Service]
 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/somejob
 User=dlt
 Type=forking

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The script is called is as follows (calling a simple routine that listens on a tcpip socket and appends the input to a file):

```
 #!/bin/sh

 cd /home/user/tmp/testout
 nohup java -jar /home/user/programming/tests/java/core/SocketTest/SocketTest.jar </dev/null >/dev/null &
```

After `systemctl start somejob` process shows as running, with `init` as its parent:

```
 user@CANTANDO ~$ ps -u dlt eo pid,ppid,command
   PID  PPID COMMAND
  8718     1 java -jar /home/user/programming/tests/java/core/SocketTest/SocketTest.jar
```

After performing `systemctl stop somejob` the process doesn't show anymore (and the port is closed).

*So everything seems fine and dandy*

My question is: Is this an **acceptable solution** for running a java daemon with `systemd`, or are there caveats, and thus other more stable or secure ways to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 18):

Here's some minor modifications:

1. Since it listens on a network socket, make it a dependency of `network.target`.
2. `nohup` is not needed since `systemd` will daemonize the executable for you.
3. I think a separate shell script would be an overkill, so just merge it into the service file.
4. Redirection (`< /dev/null` and so forth) isn't needed since systemd sets up an appropriate standard I/O context.  Indeed, if you take the redirection *out* systemd will log anything sent to standard output by the Java program in its journal, with no special logging mechanism required.
5. Running asynchonously from the invoking shell (`&`) isn't needed or appropriate.
6. There's a specific behaviour pattern required by `Type=forking`, and if it isn't followed by the dæmon things go wrong.  So try for `Type=simple` (or `Type=notify`).

So the service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some job
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/user/tmp/testout
SyslogIdentifier=SocketTest
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "exec java -jar /home/user/programming/tests/java/core/SocketTest/SocketTest.jar"
User=dlt
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Notes:

1. You cannot just use `java` as the name of the program to run.  systemd doesn't search `PATH` for executables, and the name of the executable given to `ExecStart` must be absolute.  So if you want path searching you have to invoke via a shell or `/usr/bin/env`.  We choose `/bin/sh` here.
2. Because this is `Type=simple` the shell must `exec` Java, not run it as a child process.  systemd controls the service through the main process, and that needs to be Java, not a parent shell process.
3. Because this isn't invoking the Java executable directly, systemd will put the name `sh` in its journal as the service name.  See [How to avoid /usr/bin/env being marked in systemd logs as the executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229523/) for more on this.

As far as I know, there is no special caveat of running Java application with Systemd.

Comment: That won't work.  Problem 1: This isn't the shell; there are no redirection operators.  You don't really want that redirection anyway.  Problem 2: ExecStart demands absolute pathnames.  Problem 3: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229523/

Comment: Nice head up.  I can only manage to fix problem 1.  How do you go about fixing Prob 2,3?

Comment: See the answer as edited.

Comment: I don't think the sh is necessary here.

Comment: Hello @Yun-ChihChen how do you stop the process. What does ExecStrop would look like? I have been using init.d along with a pid file but found this easier. So I needed to make sure I know how to stop etc. Thanks

Comment: @blacksensei Possibly not at all. If `ExecStop` is not specified, systemd stops a service by sending a `SIGINT` to that process. Not sure if it works the same way with a shell in between, though.