# Open file limits not increased for redis user despite change in /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: security, limit, ulimit, open-files

I got

> ERR max number of clients reached

from my `redis` server so I decidied to increase the allowed max client connections in its configuration. This also requires according to the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/clients), to increase the respective open file limits for the user.

So I made the following changes:

```
$ grep maxclient /etc/redis/redis.conf 
  maxclients 100000


$ grep redis /etc/security/limits.conf
  redis          -       nofile         100000
```

Then I did `systemctl restart redis-server`

However, when I check the limits for the `redis-server` process which is run by the system user `redis`, the max allowed files report something else:

```
  $ ps -u redis
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
    21168 ?        00:00:22 redis-server
  $ grep 'open files' /proc/21168/limits
    Max open files            4096                 4096                 files
```

Do I need to reboot the machine for the changes to take effect? Or is it something else?

Comment: Systemd ignores ulimits set by limits.conf: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345595/173368

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/security/limits.conf` is the configuration file for the [pam_limits](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_limits) PAM module. It only affects users logging in with PAM, *not* services started in other ways.

You'll need to configure systemd to change the limits on the processes it starts, see e.g. [How to set ulimits on service with systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/how-to-set-ulimits-on-service-with-systemd) on how to do that.