# "Too Many Open Files" for Apache and java/tomcat. How to set per-process limits?

Tags: limit

This problem has now appeared twice on my production Ubuntu machine running both a node server (tiny) and a Spring Boot Java server (the workhorse). The first time it happened, grinding my server to a halt I found the file `/proc/sys/fs/file-max` had a value of `808286` which seemed totally reasonable to me BUT I increased it anyway to `2097152` and then don't recall what I did after that (this was a good year ago or so?) but I probably either restarted the server or at least my service and dusted my hands of the problem. Well today it just came back to haunt me again. Restarting my Java service has temporarily fixed the problem but I want to understand what is happening to avoid this in the future.

- `/etc/security/limits.conf` file is the default one installed my Ubuntu and thus is just a file of comments so no need to reproduce here.
- Java service is run by a user `tomcat`.
- Apache is run by `root`. This directs traffic to either the node or Spring Boot services.

The result of some relevant commands on my system ...

```
$ ulimit -Sn
1024

$ ulimit -Hn
1048576

$ sudo su tomcat

$ ulimit -Sn
1024

$ ulimit -Hn
1048576
```

Side question, why is my hard limit **half** the value of that set in `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`?

But now if I look at the limits per process I get the following...

```
$ cat /proc/<tomcat_java>/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            4096                 4096                 files

$ cat /proc/<root_apache>/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            8192                 8192                 files     

$ cat /proc/<my_random_process>/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max open files            1024                 1048576              files
```

So, what is going on here? The only processes that I can find that pay attention to the file-max that I have set are my own. (The "random" process I used above was my bash shell). Where are these limits for apache and java coming from. I can certainly see blowing the 4096 limit above (which is probably my problem) but I have no idea how to get it to use the system set limits.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question looks like [How to set ulimits on service with systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/how-to-set-ulimits-on-service-with-systemd) - the open files limit needs to be addressed in the start-up script of the Apache Tomcat server. For example: assuming that the Ubuntu machine uses systemd, one can increase the open files limit for the tomcat java process to 65000 by editing the start-up script file like this:

```
/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:

[Unit]
Description=Tomcat Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
LimitNOFILE = 65000      <---------
....
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reload deamons and restart tomcat server...

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart tomcat
```

Verify, something similar with...

```
pstree -pu |grep tomcat
       |-java(23638,tomcat)-+-{java}(23645)
grep open /proc/23638/limits
Max open files            65000                65000                files
```

Comment: That does indeed appear to be what I need to do. Thank you!!