# rhel 7 setting stack size to unlimited

Tags: rhel, limit, ulimit, stack

I have some old code that needs the stack to not be limited to 8192kb in order for it to run.
I am used to doing this in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
* stack   hard    unlimited
* stack   soft    unlimited
```

However in RHEL 7.9 having a local account with a bash shell when I do a `ulimit -s` it still responds with `8192`.  So my modification of limits.conf seems to have no affect?

In my terminal window having a bash shell if I do a `ulimit -s unlimited` first then run my code, my code runs fine.

What is the best way to set stack size to unlimited, globally for all users in RHEL 7.9 ?

Am I missing something, is `ulimit` and `/etc/security/limits.conf` not the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Using **ulimit** command to set limits will change the limits for the current spawned process (shell) and its children only.

For example if you do :

```
#With root
ulimit -s unlimited
#Switch to other user 
su - <user>
ulimit -s  ## unlimited ; because this still be a child process
```

But if you do :

```
  #With root
  ulimit -s unlimited
  #Logout
  logout
  #Login as the other user then execute the following
  ulimit -s ## 8192
```

Using **/etc/security/limits.conf** will set them permanently but you have to relogin ( New Session ) to they can be effective.

If even setting stack within **/etc/security/limits.conf**  is not effective then check if it's been overridden under **/etc/security/limits.d/** or look at your profile files ~/.bash_profile ~/.bashrc.

Also check if the above is available under /**etc/pam.d/password-auth** and **/etc/pam.d/system-auth** so you are sure that **/etc/security/limits.conf** is loaded :

```
session requires pam_limits.so
```

Comment: it's `session required`  correct?

Comment: yeah I have that under pam.d.  A test pc running same exact rhel 7.9 setup, is fine with stack unlimited.  But my server it seems like what I have in `/etc/security/limit.conf` is not being put into effect.  I am stumped.

Comment: I suppose I'll reboot the server when I can and see if that fixes it.  I don't know what else to check at this point.

Comment: Yes i don't see any other thing that can block this from working :)

Comment: I think it might be systemd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/how-to-set-ulimits-on-service-with-systemd

Comment: You can test and let me know.

Comment: Is that a typo or mistake on your server? Should be `/etc/security/limits.conf` not limit.conf