# Too many open files despite a sufficiently high open files limit

Tags: linux, kernel, ulimit

I'm running a daemon that routinely stats and opens files. It also copies the data from these files over the network to various cloud providers. The daemon runs as a single process. After the process starts I increase the open file limit from the system default of 1024 to 32768 with `prlimit --pid <the process id> --nofile=32768:32768`. I've verified that the soft and hard file limits do actually get updated.

**Note**: When I mention currently open files, I'm referring to the value as returned by `lsof` continually running in another window (`while [ true ]; do sudo lsof -p <the process id> | wc -l; done;`). It's not just some guess.

The server runs fine for a while, and even under high load it has <3500 files open. However, sometimes under moderate load when only a few hundred files are open (<500) the process starts receiving "too many open files" errors when trying to create sockets, open files, stat files, etc.

Is there some other variable/limit that I'm not accounting for that would cause 'too many open files' even though the soft limit is at 32768 and only a few hundred are actually shown to be open?

Relevant info:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6
- Kernel 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 (I know it's ancient. It's not in my control)

Just to be completely clear, by the kernel's own records (via `lsof`), the process is not using too many open files. When these errors start occurring the kernel reports only a few hundred open file descriptors (with a process limit of 32768).

Comment: Are you using systemd to handle your daemon? 
Also does your process fork after starting, specifically in regards to when it copies that aforementioned files?

Comment: I'm using systemd, but manually setting the open files limit with `prlimit` after launch. The daemon never forks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why its doing this, but the first thing I would have down would be to [set the ulimit before the daemon is started](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345595/how-to-set-ulimits-on-service-with-systemd).

Answer (score 0):

Rehashing [symcbean's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/656635/290574)

systemd handles limits on a per-process basis, which subsequently means it ignores other limits, so its actually necessary to configure the limit within that service's unit file.

The following is an example:

```
[Unit]
Description=example systemd service unit file.

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/sbin/example.sh
LimitNOFILE=32768

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[Additional Documentaton](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Process%20Properties)