# Problem setting up systemd service to run screen at reboot

Tags: systemd, gnu-screen

I have a remote server running CentOS 7 I can only access by SSH.
I want two java servers running on them at all times, even after ISP does reboots etc. S

So I have tried to make a systemd service that starts the two java servers in a screen. I do not get any error messages when I start the service but it instantly dies: (systemctl status -l blogpatcher.service)

```
    * blogpatcher.service - Start blogpatcher servers
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/blogpatcher.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-02-08 04:19:09 EST; 7s ago
Process: 22388 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/blogpatc/script/blogpatcher.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 22388 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Here is blogpatcher.service file:

```
# vi /etc/systemd/system/blogpatcher.service

[Unit]

Description=Start blogpatcher servers

After=network.target


[Service]

Type=simple

ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/blogpatc/script/blogpatcher.sh

TimeoutStartSec=90


[Install]

WantedBy=default.target
```

Here is the script file that the service run:

```
# vi /var/tmp/test_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS syn bash -c 'cd /home/blogpatc/server/;java -cp bloghelper_artifact_main.jar com.aperico.bloghelper.server.ThesaurusServer;exec bash'
```

If I just run the script file from SSH console it works as intended and since there is no error message I am a bit stumped and wondering if anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Is there a way to get the output from the bash script when the service runs it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding: "RemainAfterExit=yes" under the [Service] section will let the screen remain open.

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably is `exec bash` at the end. The `bash` gets no input and therefore it exits. If you do an exec of any shell, that does the same: no input left, so the shell exits.

But more fundamentally: why use `screen`? What is the advantage here?

What is the problem with just letting the systemd do the restarting?

```
[Unit]
Description=Start blogpatcher server  
After=network.target

[Service]   
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/blogpatc/script/blogpatcher.sh
TimeoutStartSec=90
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/blogpatc/server/
java -cp bloghelper_artifact_main.jar com.aperico.bloghelper.server.ThesaurusServer
```

Systemd has a lot of additional parameters and possibilities You might want to read-up on them. For example, if the script is used just for setting the working directory (and not as a beginning for a more elaborate start-up script as I assumed), you might want to look at `WorkingDirectory`, as JdeBP suggested in the comments.

If you insist that `screen` must be used in the start-up script, then the service part of your unit file should probably be something like:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/blogpatc/server/
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -L -dm java -cp bloghelper_artifact_main.jar com.aperico.bloghelper.server.ThesaurusServer
```

or explore `Type=forking` instead of `Type=simple`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent bash from exiting?

Comment: I tried adding "exec $SHELL" at the end of the script to keep it alive but I get the same results

Comment: The extra script is entirely superfluous here.  Use the `WorkingDirectory` setting and invoke Java directly.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320319/5132

Comment: Adding things to that superfluous script that [`grep` the output of `ps`, is very much the wrong thing to do here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#The_risk_of_parsing_the_process_tree).

Comment: Why do you guys not want to answer the question? The question is on how to achieve this with screen. Maybe I have my reasons why I need it to start it in a screen.

Comment: The point is, that there is seldom a need to start a service with `screen`. But since you so explicitly ask, here's a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the `exec` command to screen which replaces the bash process with the screen process. This allows `systemctl` to recognise when your screen process terminates and use its restart-policy mechanism to restart it. This is the altered script:

```shellsession
# vi /var/tmp/test_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
exec screen -dmS syn bash -c 'cd /home/blogpatc/server/;java -cp bloghelper_artifact_main.jar com.aperico.bloghelper.server.ThesaurusServer;exec bash'
```

And this is how you specify your restart-policy:

```ini
[Service]
# ...
Restart=always
```