# Unknown lvalue 'After network.target' in section 'Unit' Centos 7

Tags: centos, services

I modified unit files according to your post:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Portal Service
After=network.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=my-portal
Environment=SERVICE_NAME=my-portal
Environment=PATH_TO_TARGET=/opt/apps/egp/stage/my-portal/target
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env java -jar ${PATH_TO_TARGET}/${SERVICE_NAME}.jar server ${PATH_TO_TARGET}/${SERVICE_NAME}.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also run command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

to reload systemd manager configuration.

All is working fine - I can successfully start, stop and see the status of the service using:

```
 systemctl start my-portal
 systemctl status my-portal -l
 systemctl stop my-portal
```

And after I fix the problem with Java env variables - I will run this command:

```
systemctl enable service-name
```

to start service (services- 5 in total) on boot.

The problem I have is setting Java env variables. I tried various versions: adding them in .bash_profile and using source command,then writing Java env in separate javaenv.sh file in /etc/profile.d folder:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_80
export PATH=/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:$PATH
```

Gave permission:

```
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/javaenv.sh
```

and modified unit file adding ${JAVA_HOME}/bin in ExecStart line...
It does not finding Java. I had the same problem before, when I was using sh scripts getting the error:

```
nohup: failed to run command â€˜javaâ€™: No such file or directory
```

I read many posts on that issue - but cannot find the solution to set Java variables in one place and use them in other units or script files as ${JAVA_HOME} variables.

Where to set Java env variables to be used in various places permanently without logging?

Comment: Solved. I added Java env (JAVA_HOME and $JAVA_HOME/bin) to  to /etc/environment file and added sym link to my java in usr/bin: ln -s /opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/java /usr/bin/java

Comment: sudo ln -s $(which java) /usr/bin/java

Answer (score 4):

## `.INI` file syntax basics

```
[Unit]
Description = My Portal Service
After network.target = my-portal.service
```

In the section `Unit` the key is supposed to be `After` and the value is (for example) `network.target my-portal.service`.  You have a key of `After network.target` and a value `my-portal.service`.  That key means nothing to systemd, as the message told you.

## Outright systemd *House of Horror* stuff

Making a service ordered to start after itself is ludicrous.  But that's just the tip of the iceberg here.

```
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/my-portal.sh start
ExecStop = /usr/local/bin/my-portal.sh stop
ExecReload = /usr/local/bin/my-portal.sh reload
…
PATH_TO_LOG="/var/log/egp"
…
PID_PATH_NAME=/var/run/${SERVICE_NAME}-pid
nohup … >> ${PATH_TO_LOG}/${SERVICE_NAME}.out 2>&1&
```

All of this is just the classic pattern, strangely predominant with Java, of erecting a foolish mess of wholly unnecessary and erroneous scaffolding.

You don't need the shell script *at all*.  You certainly don't need the rickety and dangerous PID file mechanism that it tries to employ.  Nor do you need a hand-rolled logging mechanism that relies upon a rickety logrotate/newsyslog mechanism, and cannot prevent your disc volume from filling up with log output (written by a process with superuser privileges, so it will even eat into the superuser-reserved emergency disc space) in many cases.

Use the service manager features that exist:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/my-portal.service
[Unit]
Description=My Portal Service
Documentation=https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434726/5132
After=network.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=my-service
Environment=SERVICE_NAME=my-service
Environment=PATH_TO_TARGET="/opt/apps/egp/stage/my-service/target"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env java -jar ${PATH_TO_TARGET}/${SERVICE_NAME}.jar server ${PATH_TO_TARGET}/${SERVICE_NAME}.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To read the service's log, just use `journalctl` in the usual way.  A service manager tracks processes by remembering their process IDs from when it spawned them, and has no need of the rickety and dangerous PID file mechanism.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Wrapping Apache Tomcat in many pointless extra layers*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/tomcat.html)  The systemd House of Horror.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015).  [*The systemd House of Horror*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  Frequently Given Answers.
- [How to avoid /usr/bin/env being marked in systemd logs as the executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229523/)
- [configure java daemon with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320314/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Don't use `logrotate` or `newsyslog` in this century.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I inherited the scripts and SW service. I follow the instructions and could start the services (5 in total) in VBox (Centos 7 min) and they were working fine. - that is strange. On another cloud instance it gives this error. I am new to services,  but started reading systemd docs. My apology for not answering before, I am literary forced to do some other tasks and soon I will be back - and write the feedback. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You misplaced an equals character in `my-portal.service`. Also, you should get rid of the shell script and get SystemD to manage the process directly.

Try this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Portal Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=Simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/apps/egp/stage/my-portal/target/my-portal.jar server /opt/apps/egp/stage/my-portal/target/my-portal.yml

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```