# systemd service file for a node.js app is not working when pointed at a shell script

Tags: systemd, services, node.js

Before I mention my problem, I have already checked in most of the questions related to systemd, but I couldn't find a convincing answer. I wrote a nodejs app that runs a server.

```
const express = require('express');
const app     = express(),
      port    = process.env.PORT || 5000;

    app.get('/' , ( req , res ) => {
        res.send('Hello World')
    })

    app.listen( port , () => {
        console.log(`The server listens on port ${port}`)
    })
```

Initially, I created a service that runs the server.js and it worked like a charm.

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello World
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/msimou/Desktop/helloWorld/server.js
User=msimou
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, I tried the same task by creating .sh files that either start or stop the service and I tried to embedded in the unit file, but for some unknown reason the server is not working. The updated unit file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello World
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/msimou/Desktop/helloWorld/init/startHelloWorld.sh
ExecStop=/bin/bash /home/msimou/Desktop/helloWorld/init/stopHelloWorld.sh
User=msimou
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I checked in the logs files at `/var/log/syslog` and `journalctl` to spot the error but the only thing that I can see is systemd to continuously start and stop my service evety 5 seconds. When I checked using `systemctl status helloWorld.service`, its said that the service had a success status, however I couldn't find any process related to my nodejs application.

Comment: What do those bash scripts do, exactly? Suspect systemd is watching the bash pid and not your node app...

Comment: Said a different way, why do you need a shell script to start & stop it? Systemd keeps track, so you should be able to `systemctl start helloWorld` and `systemctl stop helloWorld`...

Comment: The ExecStop= is optional, it is used to communicate with the service for a clean termination. The process specified by ExecStop will run in case the service crashes. In the absence of any ExecStop option, the systemctl stop servicename command will simply kill the remaining processes of the unit, as specified by the KillMode option.

Comment: Similar problem to link in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/437251/117549

Answer (score 6):

Since you did not specify a service type, `systemd` will assume the default `Type=simple`.

As a result, `systemd` assumes that your `ExecStart` command will start the actual service process. It will start that process in its own control group (cgroup), and will monitor it. Any children of the `ExecStart` process will be members of the same control group.

When the `ExecStart` process dies, systemd will assume it means your service died. Since you're now using a script to start the actual service, this assumption will be incorrect. At that point, it will kill any processes remaining in the control group to clean up the service (effectively killing your actual service process). Then it attempts to restart the service, and the cycle repeats...

By starting the service indirectly through a script, you effectively changed your service from the `simple` type to `forking` type, but did not tell that to `systemd`. But the `forking` type has some additional legacy baggage associated with it. It also makes it harder for `systemd` to monitor your service process; you should avoid it unless absolutely necessary.

Ideally you should keep the start of the actual service process in `ExecStart=` and have any environment variables specified in the actual `.service` file with the `Environment=` option, or in a separate file referred to by `EnvironmentFile=` option. Any extra start-up commands could become `ExecStartPre=` and/or `ExecStartPost=` options; that way you can still keep the default `Type=simple` and the automatic process monitoring it provides. You can still use `ExecStop=` with a `Type=simple` service, if needed.

---

If you use `Type=forking`, systemd will still track the service through its control group. If the service creates other processes, it won't know which of them is the main process of the service, and so you'll need to provide at least the `PIDFile=` option to help systemd kill the main service process first when stopping the service, or a suitable `ExecStop=` that does something more service-friendly than just blindly killing processes.

If the service's control group becomes empty of processes, `systemd` will still detect the service has failed. But with `Type=forking` and no `PIDFile=`, the main process of the service might die and the failure might remain undetected as long as at least one of its child processes remains.

When the `ExecStop=` process is done, if there are any processes left in the service's process group, `systemd` assumes it means the orderly shutdown failed for some reason, and will immediately use `SIGKILL` to clean up the remaining processes in the control group unless specified otherwise using the various options listed in the `systemd.kill(5)` man page.

So, if you use `Type=simple`, you won't need a `PIDFile=` and don't have to worry about what to do if a crash of the service or the entire system leaves you with a stale PID file.

If you use `Type=forking` and your service uses more than one process, you should use a `PIDFile=` so that `systemd` can correctly identify the master process of your service, both for monitoring purposes and for killing when necessary.

If your service needs a more elaborate shutdown process than just "send a `SIGTERM` to its main/only process", use `ExecStop=` regardless of the `Type=` option, but be aware that it needs to handle any necessary wait/timeout too; the expected result is that the service shutdown is *completed* when the `ExecStop=` process ends. If there are any remaining processes in the service's control group after that, `systemd` will assume they can safely be killed and will immediately use `SIGKILL` to clean them up.

Comment: When I added a Type=forking the script worked. What if i refer a PIDFile? Is it still recommended not for  use?

Comment: Updated to more fully describe the complications of `Type=forking`.